# Cannot using 'map' method when function return array or number

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

When I run this code below it has error: "[ts]
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'number | number[]'.
  Property 'map' does not exist on type 'number'"

```js
const a = [
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
]

const testFunc : (data: number[], options?: string) => number[] | number = function (data: number[], options?: string) {
  if (options === 'array') return [1, 2, 3]
  return 1
}
const whichType = testFunc(a, 'array')
const double = whichType.map(item => item*2)
```

When I hover 'whichType' it shows me that is number. But actually is not a nummber
Does anyone know why 'whichType' is not 'number[]'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`whichType` is a union type of `number | number[]`.

You need to narrow it to use it:

```
if (typeof whichType === 'number') {
    // It's a number
} else {
    // It's an array
    const double = whichType.map(item => item * 2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. you save my day